# Getting the log level in python

Tags: python, logging

After setting the level to `info`:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

Is there a way I can print the `level` to confirm it's set to `logging.INFO` ? I was hoping `logging.__dict__` would show it, but I can't find it from that dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> logging.getLevelName(logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel())
'INFO'
```

The call to `.getEffectiveLevel()` returns the numeric code of the level, and from there you get the level name via the appropriately named `.getLevelName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
import logging
lvl = logging.INFO

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=lvl)    
print(logging.getLevelName(lvl))
>>>INFO
```